# DynamoDB - Update or Create if not found method

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDB, how can I make an update or create if not found method if I have a hash key and a range key in my table.  Below works if I have a table with only a hash key, but not for tables with a hash and range key:

```
 var save = function(user_id, store_id, callback){

    var DOC = require('dynamodb-doc'),
    docClient = new DOC.DynamoDB();

    var params = {
        TableName: 'stores',
        ReturnValues: 'NONE',
        Key: {
            'user_id': user_id
        },
        ConditionExpression: "#a = :store_id_val",
        UpdateExpression: 'SET #a = :store_id_val',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#a': 'store_id'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':store_id_val': store_id
        }
    };

    // Save DynamoDB Document
    docClient.updateItem(params, function(error, response) {
        return callback(error, response);
    });
  }
```

Comment: if you have hash and range keys - you should indicate both in `Key`

Comment: Lashane, is it that simple?  Do I just specify both in the Key object?

Comment: hash and range - both parts of the key, of course you _have_ to specify both

Comment: Then it is that simple.  Thank you Lashane.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.  I just need to specify both hash and range key in the `Key` parameter.  Then I can get away with this:

```
var save = function(user_id, store_id, callback) {

    var DOC = require('dynamodb-doc'),
        docClient = new DOC.DynamoDB();

    var params = {
        TableName: 'stores',
        ReturnValues: 'NONE',
        Key: {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'store_id': store_id
        }
    };

    // Save DynamoDB Document
    docClient.updateItem(params, function(error, response) {
        return callback(error, response);
    });
}
```